# Wifi Permissions per User

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012, wifi, file-permissions, unifi

I was sitting here thinking about Wifi, permissions and file access. I wanted to know if there's a way to setup individual user and passwords on wifi sort of the same way you do on a windows server but also set permissions to what files/folders they can access on the server when connected to WIFI? Is there a device or special type of WIFI product that allows you to do this?

Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an AD domain, you can set up RADIUS role on your Windows Server 2012. UniFi (both from the tags) can use RADIUS for WPA2 Enterprise authentication; either for users or even better, for devices. If you use Group Policy for setting up WiFi profiles with *computer authentication*, all your Windows devices with AD computer account can connect to the WiFi without giving usernames and passwords, but you'd still need *user authentication* for BYOD devices.

Unfortunately the file access doesn't come directly from the RADIUS authentication, but with AD connected devices you already have the access from the logged-in user account. That's how it's done professionally on a Windows AD domain.

Comment: similiar works for samba/freeradius when using linux.

Comment: @DennisNolte. True. This question was about Windows Server 2012 and UniFi.

Comment: True enough, i didnt read the question as specifically searching a solution for windows/unify but instead as a "general" way of method.